# Character sequence messes up the order of characters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I had to handle an exception, by catching it and matching the message and if the message contains a certain error code, do something (not relevant).

The exceptions message is this (in English, but the code and the gibberish after it is the same in any language):

```
$-5002 - $make sure that the consumed quantity of the component item would not cause the item's stock to fall below zero  [ige1.whscode][line: 1] , 'production order no: 20580033 line: 1'  [الرسالة 3559-7]
```

I had to work with the code `7-3559` (as displayed). In my code, I just did a `e.Message.Contains("7-3559")` and it failed to catch the exception. Wondering what went wrong I copy pasted the error massage to regex101.com and after a bit of trial and error I realized that `e.Message.Contains("3559-7")` is the real code and it works. I just don't know why. What messes up the string to display it in such a way that `7-` is actually `-7` and also behind `3559`?

I guess I should also mention I am working with Visual Studio 2019 and C#.

*[Check out the regex here.](https://regex101.com/r/ehHTkD/1/)*
[image: https://regex101.com/r/ehHTkD/1/]

HxD:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably due to the arabic word at the end. Anyhow, try using `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in the Contains function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue encountered when using bidirectional text, in other words, a text that contains both texts directionality: Right-to-Left (RTL) such as Arabic texts, and Left-to-Right (LTR).

Here we have the Arabic text mixed with English text so some rules will be applied to the text to determine the directionality. You may find details about this [here](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

In short, the text you see in the debugger is how the text will appear when you print it but not how it is represented in memory.

Here I use Linqpad to paste the text and the editor has immediately transformed it into the representation in memory. And once printed, the text is shown with a different directionality.

[image]